# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, bindparam

I am getting this error in PHP
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\makePitch\include\DB_Functions.php on line 33

```
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pitches(image_url,trader_id,product_type,price,location) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sisis", $image_url,$trader_id,$product_type,$price,$location);
```

Comment: Short answer: The call to `prepare()` is failing (and returning `false`).  Check for SQL errors after preparing and before trying to use the result.